# Angular: test interceptor correct requests order

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, karma-jasmine

Consider the following interceptor example

```
export class RefreshTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.jwtService.isExpired()) {
      return this.handleTokenRefresh(request, next);
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  private handleTokenRefresh(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.jwtService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token);

          return next.handle(request);
        }))
    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token !== null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(jwt => {
          return next.handle(request);
        }));
    }
  }
}
```

The aim is to delay http requests until refresh token resolved.

Here is a test for this method.

```
  let JwtServiceMock: any;
  let interceptor: RefreshTokenInterceptor;
  let httpHandlerSpy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    JwtServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('JwtService', ['isExpired', 'refreshToken']);

    httpHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);
    httpHandlerSpy.handle.and.callFake((param) => {
      return of(param);
    });

    interceptor = new RefreshTokenInterceptor(JwtServiceMock)
  });


it('multiple requests', fakeAsync(() => {
  jwtService.isExpired.and.returnValue(true);

  let httpRequestMock1 = { url: '/url1' } as HttpRequest<any>;
  let httpRequestMock2 = { url: '/url2' } as HttpRequest<any>;
  let httpRequestMock3 = { url: '/url3' } as HttpRequest<any>;

  JwtServiceMock.refreshToken.and.returnValue(
    of({ token: 'whatever' }).pipe(delay(1000))
  );

  interceptor.intercept(httpRequestMock1, httpHandlerSpy).subscribe();
  interceptor.intercept(httpRequestMock2, httpHandlerSpy).subscribe();
  interceptor.intercept(httpRequestMock3, httpHandlerSpy).subscribe();

  tick(1100);

  expect(JwtServiceMock.refreshToken).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(httpHandlerSpy.handle).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  expect(httpHandlerSpy.handle.calls.argsFor(2)).toEqual([httpRequestMock1]);
  expect(httpHandlerSpy.handle.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([httpRequestMock2]);
  expect(httpHandlerSpy.handle.calls.argsFor(1)).toEqual([httpRequestMock3]);
}));
```

And here is the problem - I expect requests to be sent in the same order, as they hit in the interceptor - httpRequestMock1, httpRequestMock2, httpRequestMock3. And this is how it actually works through web interface. But for some reason, I can't reproduce it in the test - it returns incorrect order httpRequestMock2, httpRequestMock3, httpRequestMock1. Obviously, the test is incorrect. What I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for **httpRequestMock2**, **httpRequestMock3**, **httpRequestMock1** order is as below:

First request(`interceptor.intercept` method call) enters the if condition where you are calling `JwtService.refreshToken` and you have configured jasmine test to mock it with (**`delay`**) rxJS operator and the rest of two calls to intercept method goes directly without calling `JwtService.refreshToken` so no delay is observed and hence *httpRequestMock2* and *httpRequestMock3* gets resolved earlier than *httpRequestMock1*.

Comment: but 2 and 3 depends on 1, they should wait till `this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token)` called, which is also delayed. it makes sense actually